# TypeError: cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

When I try to add static dirs to my code, I get this error :

`TypeError: cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined`

Can anyone help me with this ?

```
['adobeair','applewebkit','bs3','chrome','css','font-awesome','hpwos','images','img','js', 'Opera', 'plugins'].forEach(function (dir)
{
    app.use('/template/'+dir, connect.static(__dirname+'/template/'+dir));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce with your posted code

Comment: Solved by using app.use('/template',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'template')));   Thanks :)

Comment: forEach() works in Array and IE>9
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Best way -

```
var dirs = ['adobeair','applewebkit','bs3','chrome','css','font-awesome','hpwos','images','img','js', 'Opera', 'plugins'];

dirs.forEach(function(dir) { 

console.log('dir name : '+dir);

});
```

It is working or me :)